# Why coroutine gets stopped?

Tags: unity, c#, coroutines

Here's my code:

```
IEnumerator SceneIsInChange(AsyncOperation SecondScene)
    {
        Snake.SetActive(true);
        print("1: " + FinalLoop);
        while (!SecondScene.isDone)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        Snake.GetComponent<Animator>().SetBool("Loaded", true);
        print("2: " + FinalLoop);
        while (!FinalLoop)
        {
            yield return null;
        }
        print("3: " + FinalLoop);
        Time.timeScale = 1;
        Loading = false;
        LoadingScene = null;
    }
```

The problem is that the coroutine gets suspended before `print("2: " + FinalLoop);` line. (But `print("1: " + FinalLoop` works) So the problem should be in the first while loop but I can't find it. There's only one single code in that loop but it's supposed to "wait for one frame before resuming coroutine" so it shouldn't stop the coroutine.

Am I wrong about `yield return null;` meaning or the problem is somewhere else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Hesamom I found a solution:

All you need to do is to add `AsyncOperation.allowSceneActivation = false` so it won't activate itself right after loading, and then change it to `true` once you did all you wanted (usually at the last line of coroutine)

Answer (score 2):

Coroutines are stopped when their corresponding game object is deactivated or destroyed, regarding your code logic, it's possible after the scene change, the game object in previous scene as well as Its coroutine are destroyed

Your assumption about yield return null is also true

Comment: I don't get it. According to what I've seen in tutorials, the scene won't change until the coroutine is finished, isn't that correct?

Comment: Scene loading is not dependent on any coroutine by default unless you set "allowSceneActivation" property of the operation to false from the beginning and set to true in the end of coroutine

Comment: Hey, thanks! I didn't know about that property

Comment: You're welcome, please mark my answer as accepted